# How can I - Count the occurances of a \ in a line in a text file using windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

In this thread - [How can you show directories by level not by structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455688/how-do-i-do-this-producing-a-dir-listing-by-level-not-by-following-structu)

I try to explain an almost impossible task I have been given.

I have been working on finding a way to automate it using a Windows batch file and think I have boiled the problem down to being able to count the number of \ characters there are either in a variable or a single line file and then do something depending on the result.

Looking around these forums showed folk doing similar things so I tried to amend one of the answers to this -

```
echo off
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion      
set fold=E:\*.  
dir %fold%  
dir %fold% /s /b > out1.txt  
set /A level=1  
echo LEVEL %level%  
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%I IN (out1.txt) do (  
SET LN=%%I  
echo %%I  
SET TOTAL=0  
FOR %%J IN ("!LN!") do (  
    FOR /F %%K IN ('ECHO %%J ^| FIND /I /C "\"') DO (  
        @SET /A TOTAL=!TOTAL!+%%K & echo %%K  
    )  
)  
echo tot=!TOTAL!  
)
```

What I am trying to do is extract a single line from a bare dir place it into a file and count the number of times a \ appears.

However I just cannot get it to work.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: `find /c` doesn't count occurences, but *lines* that have the search string (maybe several times)

Comment: you may want to use `dir /ad` (print directories only). Much more secure than `dir *.` (as directory names can also contain dots)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll fix the dir issue. Is there any way to count occurrences?

Comment: see your original question. Give me some time to add some explanations.

Comment: I vote to close this question as duplicate. And because this clearly is a [X-Y-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)